# OpenLayers 3 keeps showing tile from lower zoom level

Tags: openlayers-3

in my application, developed with OpenLayers 3.6.0, I have the problem, that after zooming in at the edge of the area, for which tiles exist, a part of a line feature seems to show the blown up tile from the previous zoom level.

You should be able to reproduce this by entering the following URL in any browser and zooming in using the plus button:

> `http://www.basemap.at/application/index.html#{"center":[1914116.9361742584,6087116.001148832],"zoom":14,"rotation":0,"layers":"1000000000"}`

I am not sure, if this is a bug in OpenLayers. Therefore, before opening an issue, I would like to ask, if another developer has already seen the same problem and has somehow solved it.

Best Regards,
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your application is an insufficient tile grid definition. The server responds with 404 errors for unavailable tiles. By adding the extent of your tile set to your tile grid definition, you can avoid 404 tiles, and the issue should go away.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwmvg9ef/2/) to show you the correct configuration for your application. It boils down to a `tileGrid` definition like this:

```js
tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
  origin: [-20037508.3428, 20037508.3428],
  extent: [977649.9582335392, 5838029.951202585, 1913529.9492146818, 6281289.924879572],
  resolutions: [156543.03392811998, 78271.51696419998, 39135.758481959994, 19567.879241008, 9783.939620504, 4891.969810252, 2445.984905126, 1222.9924525644, 611.4962262807999, 305.74811314039994, 152.87405657047998, 76.43702828523999, 38.21851414248, 19.109257071295996, 9.554628535647998, 4.777314267823999, 2.3886571339119995, 1.1943285669559998, 0.5971642834779999, 0.29858214174039993],
  matrixIds: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"]
})
```

Comment: Is this something the user can do?  I use tiles from a third-party server and if they don't have the tile I get a 404 from them - I don't know which tiles are and are not defined on this third-party server, so how can I code for that?  Could we not hook up a 404 not found and then feed a transparent png back through OL?

Comment: This is something the user can do. A third-party server has some kind of metadata or capabilities document where things like extent and origin are documented.

Comment: If you want to handle 404 errors instead, you can register for the source's tileerror event and take appropriate action.

Comment: When I add extent to the tileGrid settings like this

    var tilegrid = new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
        //origin: [-20037508.3428, 20037508.3428],
        extent: [977650, 5838030, 1913530, 6281290],
        resolutions: [
            559082264.029 * 0.28E-3,
            ...
    });

I get an empty map. If I keep origin uncommented, a small part of the map is shown. I cannot understand, what I have done wrong.

Comment: @GerhardSommer If you can create a JSFiddle with the code you have now, I can help you make it work.

Comment: @GerhardSommer You can also look at the official OpenLayers example that uses the same data source, but configures it from WMTS capabilities: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/wmts-hidpi.html. As you can see, the tiles in question work fine there.

Comment: @GerhardSommer I updated my answer with a link to a working JSFiddle, and a code snippet that shows the correct tile grid configuration. It is basically the same as the one you posted in your comment. Maybe you forgot to add the matrixIds, or something else in your application is wrong.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help. It simply was my version of OpenLayers (3.6.0). The extent seems to need at least 3.7.0.

Comment: Glad I could help @GerhardSommer. Please mark my answer as correct if it was useful.